# IE11 and Chrome different encoding

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, encoding, character-encoding

To be honest I've never been understanding encoding and such very well.
Please help me out here.
This piece of html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:alert('%C3%B6');">Click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome it displays: `ö` that's what I'm expecting.

In IE it displays: `Ã¶` and that's not expected and not the desired outcome.

How can I change my code to get the browsers to behave the same way?

Comment: Why don't you use \u00f6?

Comment: I'm not following. Anyway %C3%B6 is the output when rendering a link with ASP.NET MVC which is my original case.

Comment: but JavaScript strings are not UTF8, regardless of text encoding. Chrome seems to escape also JavaScript code while IE doesn't but point is that it's not what expected (I'm surprised Chrome does it, BTW I can't reproduce it). If it's URL encoding then it has nothing to do with javascript alert()...and you should post an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ho capito, grazie. Faccio un UrlDecode invece. Grazie a lei, buona giornata :)
Actually seems to work when doing UrlDecode on that link output from mvc. Never had any problem with this before these special characters showed up in my javascript string.

Answer (score 0):

You could try alerting the character itself, and not just the code, like:
`alert("ö")`